# Creating Repositories object in spring with AppContext returns proxy instead of actual repository

Tags: java, spring-data

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.3.RELEASE and whenever i create the repositories object from the application context and then call the hasRepsoitoryFor method i get the proxy.  Why doesnt it return the actual Repository class.

```
public CPDPermissionEvaluator(ApplicationContext context) {
    Assert.notNull(context);
    repositories = new Repositories(context);
}

@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
    JpaRepository repository = null;
    try {
        Class repositoryClass = Class.forName(targetType);
        Assert.isTrue(repositories.hasRepositoryFor(repositoryClass));
        repository = (JpaRepository) repositories.getRepositoryFor(repositoryClass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new DataSourceLookupFailureException("Could not find Repository for entity type[" + targetType + "]", e);
    }
    Assert.notNull(repository);
    Object domainObject = repository.getOne(targetId);
    return hasPermission(authentication, domainObject, permission);
}
```

The when that code attempts to run i get the following Exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173 cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
at uk.co.cp.digital.security.acls.CPDPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission(CPDPermissionEvaluator.java:96) ~[classes/:1.0.3]
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot.hasPermission(SecurityExpressionRoot.java:181) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:113) ~[spring-expression-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129) ~[spring-expression-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:85) ~[spring-expression-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131) ~[spring-expression-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299) ~[spring-expression-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:26) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.before(ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.java:59) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:72) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:40) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:63) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy195.cancelUser(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at uk.co.cp.digital.web.rest.resource.admin.user.AdminUserResourceController.deleteUser(AdminUserResourceController.java:103) ~[classes/:1.0.3]
at uk.co.cp.digital.web.rest.resource.admin.user.AdminUserResourceController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1e8d2f0d.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:1.0.3]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656) ~[spring-aop-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at uk.co.cp.digital.web.rest.resource.admin.user.AdminUserResourceController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dd84128d.deleteUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:1.0.3]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:894) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:654) [servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:?]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at uk.co.cp.digital.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:45) [classes/:1.0.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [catalina.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.9]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.9]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.9]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

Any ideas or do i need to pull the target out of the proxy.  But according to Spring's docs i should be getting the actual repository class.

Comment: If you're tying it so closely to JPA, why not just go ahead and use `em.find(targetType, targetId)`?

Comment: I ended up doing it that way.  i was trying to use the spring way of doing by utilizing the Repositories class but i could not get it to work.